# Rails - Translate model name in form actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation, locale

I want to translate a rails form using i18n system.

My model attributes are translated correctly, but when I want to translate submit actions, the model name is not translated.

Here is my fr.yml locale file

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    model:
      character:
        one: "Personnage"
        other: "Personnages"
    attributes:
      character:
        name: "Nom"
        title: "Titre"
        biography: "Biographie"
  helpers:
    submit:
      update: "Mise à jour %{model}"
```

My _form.html.erb is

```
<%= form_for(@character) do |f| %>
  <% if @character.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@character.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this character from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @character.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :biography %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :biography, :rows => 8%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

On my form, I expected the update button to be "Mise à jour **Personnage**", but I still have "Mise à jour **Character**".

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you have a `model` where you should have `models`.

Change your fr.yml to look like this:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    models:
      character:
        one: "Personnage"
        other: "Personnages"
    ...
```

See the rails i18n documentation section on [Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for details.

Comment: Because I ran into this issue: if your model uses `ActiveModel` but not `ActiveRecord` directly (perhaps because you use a data mapper instead), use `activemodel.models.character` instead.

Comment: Didn't work for me, button still labeled as (in my case, pt-br) "Criar Category" instead of "Criar Categoria".

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of the submit button when used in the form_for tag...it will show the Update Character instead of "Update #{Model.name}"...